# Image with Iphone retina 4" doesn't fit in iPhone retina 3.5" inch

Tags: uiimageview, ios7, retina-display, screen-resolution

I need a image for background on my app, it is 568x162 pixels. It fir perfect in the iPhone 4" emulator, but when I try in 3.5" it seems to bi bigger than screen.
It is in landscape mode, my image name is backiphone@x2.png and the code simply is ...

```
[_imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backiphone"]];
```

I tried lot of things, but can't fit it on the 3.5" screen! Help please

Comment: Ups!, ok, now I see.. I thought it was a code problem.. cheers!

Comment: In xib or storyboard have option "AutoSizing"

Answer (score 0):

as karthuka said ... " In xib or storyboard have option "AutoSizing"  "